# How can I make this google sheets formula less awful?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16aL2pJ4hI0Z3TVlWe_8oc-scdRVM3WeNpq-CowZ-RTg/edit#gid=0

Is there a way for me to make the formula on cell A4 on the 'Table' worksheet less cluttered and awful?
It's supposed to combine all the drop-down functionality that the sheet offers, but it's just becoming a very run on formula, and it's getting on my nerves. I'm unsure I can split it either as one column will depend on another drop down so I'm unsure what to do.

I don't want to use google sheets built-in filter function because it doesn't work very well for what I'm trying to do, and not very user-friendly.

As a bonus question, the way I have the ratings drop-down work is with the following formula:
`IF(K3="All",n(Data!K1:K153)<>"", IF(K3="4+ Stars",Data!K1:K153>=4, IF(K3="3+ Stars",Data!K1:K153>=3, IF(K3="2+ Stars",Data!K1:K153>=2, IF(K3="1+ Star",Data!K1:K153>=1,Data!K1:K153=5)))))`

However, when selecting any of the "star/s" options on the drop-down, it also shows the text values, which I don't want. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Please do not assume that users can/will/should open your spreadsheet in order to better understand your question. Your question should stand on its own, and data should not be supplied **ONLY** by spreadsheet. Would you please edit your question to include sample data and sample outcome in a text table. There are several ways to create a text table including the free online service at [www.tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score -1):

For problems like this, it's better to use QUERY. I duplicated your tab and entered this formula in A4.

`=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(r,3:3,m,REGEXMATCH(r,"^(Either|All|)$")-1,QUERY(Data!A:AC,"where Col1 is not null"&REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(TEXTJOIN(,1," and "&FILTER("Col"&COLUMN(r),m)&"='"&FILTER(r,m)&"'"),"='(\d+)\+? Stars?'",">=$1"),"='At least (\d+)'",">=$1"),"='£-££'"," matches '£{1,2}'"),"='£-£££'"," matches '£{1,3}'"),"Yes","✔"),"No",),"='(\d+)'","=$1"))))`